# How much memory is needed to do bucket-sorting on 1TB of integers in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, memory, space-complexity, bucket-sort

I think the answer to this question should be 16GB, the following is how I calculate:

- One integer is 32bit
- In java, the range of integers is from -2^31 to 2^31-1, so the total number of integers is 2^32
- We need to have a int array with the size of 2^32 to do bucket sorting
- So I got the result of 32bit * 2^32 = 16GB

Can anyone tell me if this is correct? Because I found people saying this should be 4GB. I don't know how 4GB is calculated.

One example can be found: 
https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-sort-a-100-TB-file-with-only-4-GB

Comment: You can sort an unlimited amount of data with very little memory at the cost of I/O and cpu cycles, using a large number of on-disk buckets and multiple sort/merge passes.  The question is rather unclear.

Comment: 1 byte per byte is fine provided you have no more than 255 duplicates.

Comment: @Peter Lawery, you are right and this could be possible since there is 1TB integers (2^38 numbers) while the size of unique numbers is 2^32, we could have all numbers with less than 254 duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: @Lubor A starter approach might be to have a break out strategy when the count reaches 255. i.e. store the most common values in a `Map<Integer, Long>`  If there isn't a uniform distribution this could works well. If there is a uniform distribution you might have to use 16-bit counters and/or an exponent scale to estimate the count. e.g. 0 - 7 count every one, for codes 8- 15 count every second, 16 - 23 count every fourth etc This will give you a range of several billion (but is only an estimate)

Answer (score 0):

The example question linked to is not asking the same thing. A bucket sort on 1TB of integers would need 4GB of buckets, where each bucket would be 1TB * sizeof(integer) in size. This would not be a reasonable approach.

As for the linked question, to sort a large file, some variation of an external bottom up k-way merge sort would be used, probably with k == 16. The trade off on k is the number of passes it will take to do the sort (fewer passes if k is larger), versus the compare time to find the smallest element of k elements for each element merged (longer compare time if k is larger).